# Print in a Table Format Java using printf

Tags: java, format, printf

I'm building a stock control system, on this it will have a feature to print the stock list, which the stock are stored in a linked list.

How could I get the list to be printed in a tabular format, and if the description is long on the item it will still keep in a tabular format.

Currently this is the code that I have:

```
String print = String.format("%-15s %-30s %20s %18s \t\t %-18s\n", "ItemID", "Description", "Price","Qnty", "Re-Order Level")
                + String.format("%-15s %-30s %20s %18s \t\t %-18s\n", "******", "***********", "*****", "****","**************");
```

But if the text on the StockItems description is long that the others, It will deform the table look.

Here's the format method on the StockItem class:

```
String format = String.format("%-15s %-30s %20.2f %18d \t\t %-18d", itemID, itemDesc, price, quantity, reOrderLevel);
```

Comment: what about an second line with the extra chars from the description ?

Comment: Try %-30.30s. It works that way in C. I looked it up and some places say it works and some don't. It might be worth a try. The number after the <dot> is the maximum length of the string content.